# Activating touch-enabled controls in JavaFX

Tags: windows-8, javafx

I want to use the touch-enabled controls described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/embed.htm. I'm building my application on a `Windows 8` tablet, but the `ScrollPanes` are desktop-style, i.e. with `scrollbars` and no reaction to finger-dragging. How do I tell `JavaFX` that I'm on a mobile platform?

***Edit***: I just realized that the standard, desktop-style ScrollPane does react to finger-dragging, but it doesn't look like the example one in the link above.

***Solution***: the features can be enabled by setting -Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true and -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true

Answer (score -1):

There should not be a need to enable these capabilities, but JavaFX decides by itself if they are supported. You can query the capabilities programmatically, e.g. by `PlatformImpl.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.INPUT_TOUCH)`.

Comment: This returns false on the Windows 8 tablet.

Comment: I just found out that the features can be enabled by setting -Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true and -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true