# Define input type for Windows 10 touch keyboard from a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, windows-10, multitouch-keyboard

I have a working JavaFX app running on windows 10. 
I would like to use the touch-keyboard in a similar to  [MSDN user input scope to change the touch keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx)
HOWEVER there is no way to interact with it. All textfieeds open the *Default keyboard.*
I would like to find the closest to JavaFX as possible solution.

Things I have tries so far:

1. Tried to use the WM_MESSAGE to trick the OS, see [Here](http://techqa.info/programming/tag/on-screen-keyboard?after=20931849). This is a messy workaround that does not work on windows 10.
2. Encapsulating the WM_MESSAGE or InputScope object in an executable, and calling it from JNI only creates a one-way transition from app to keyboard. it will not suffice.
3. Using a custom keyboard or the JAvaFX touch keyboard (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/embed.htm) is not a valid solution as these keyboards look a bit messy, and they require some twirking we already know exist.
4. [set-numeric-layout-for-windows-onscreen-keyboard-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781166/set-numeric-layout-for-windows-onscreen-keyboard-programmatically) not working.
5. [activating-touch-enabled-controls-in-javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564413/activating-touch-enabled-controls-in-javafx) is irrelevant.